# How can I send local html file to Telegram with python bot

Tags: python, python-3.6, telegram-bot

this is my code

```
file_address = './charts/candle_chart.html'
response = bot.sendDocument(chat_id=chat_id, document=file_address, timeout=timeout)
```

but i got Exception with `host not found` error

telegram think this file in the web

can anybody help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation of telegram-bot says:

> ```
> The document argument can be either a file_id, an URL or a file from disk: open(filename, 'rb')
> ```

So it must be something like this:

```
html_file = open('./charts/candle_chart.html', 'rb')
response = bot.sendDocument(chat_id=chat_id, document=html_file, timeout=timeout)
```

For more information, see [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=sendDocument#telegram.Bot.sendDocument):

Comment: Unfortunatly, seems not to work.